Populate fields on 365 mailboxes through ExchangeOnline PS script
getting a "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null" in this script :
# Import Exchange Online PowerShell Module
Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement

# Connect to Exchange Online
Connect-ExchangeOnline

# Path to the CSV file
$csvFilePath = "mypathblabla"

# Import the CSV file
$userList = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath

# Loop through each user in the CSV file and update the City and Country attributes
foreach ($user in $userList) {
    $email = $user.Email
    $city = $user.City
    $country = $user.Country

    # Update the user attributes
    try {
        Set-Mailbox -Identity $email -City $city -CountryOrRegion $country
        Write-Host "Successfully updated $email with City: $city and Country: $country"
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Failed to update $email. Error: $_"
    }
}

I gathered it to basically put 2 different attributes in the fields "city" and "country" on a loooong list of users 365 mails contained in a csv file.
Could someone explain to me what I am missing here ? (CSV is in the good format : Email,City,Country).
Thank you very much in advance

Correct CSV
Search the error
Thought i should learn powershell extensively for this extensive type of uses ?


The error does imply bad data (column names, mismatched or missing single and/or double quotes in the file, extra comma's etc). If not then maybe file encoding of .csv file could be an issue? If you run $data | Select -First 1 | FT after loading CSV - that will show the column names and 1st row of data - does that look ok? Also copy&paste your 1st Write-Host to before Set-Mailbox command to see what its about to execute. Does output include "Successfully updated...." or "Failed to update..." and do those lines contain the executed data? Please edit your question and add more detail.

Could you post 2-3 lines of the .csv file as text. No pictures. What is the field delimiter in the .csv file?

I'm not seeing a -city or -countryorregion option in Set-Mailbox. I'm thinking you need to set it in Set-AzureADUser and that will link it with EOL.

Sorry if the first post is confused, tired and in a hurry, the fields do exist on Exchange admin but maybe there are no cmds for it, i did try with azureAD but i'm more confortable with EOL so writing it was easier, i'll go this path if i can't come up to something
csv is looking like this, field delimitor is a (;) :
Email     City    Country
x@x.x     x       x
The format table looks like x;x;x ; looking through the write host before set-mbox gets to "Skipping update etc.", maybe i should try with azureAD...

Got it to work by translating to Azure cmdlet and adding a few syntax elements ! Case closed

Hi, write a regular answer and not a comment  if this is resolved.  As is, your question cannot help others
